# Bulkify Trigger for Web to case Automation?

Tags: trigger, web-to-case

I have a need to create an automation for filling few fields on the case which are created from web to case.

I have build a trigger after insert for that purpose, but since the logic is quite complex it is very hard to bulkify the code to handle list of cases.

Since the trigger handles only case creation from web to case, is it ok write the code not bulkify?

The question is : is it possible that the web to case will send to the trigger context a list of cases ?

Comment: Why not use the case origin field to identify the records created from web-to-case and write bulkified code around it?

Comment: just because W2C might always be singleton doesn't mean that a trigger on Case should not be bulkified as there are many other use cases where Cases could be inserted in bulk and the trigger will execute